Are Shibolim rice cakes kosher for Pesach without special hechsher?
Hoping someone knows the answer or can point me where to ask.
We eat kitniyos on Pesach. I bought these Shibolim rice cakes from Walmart. Last year I recall getting it as well (I think from Amazon) and I seem to recall it specifically was labeled as kosher for Pesach kitniyot.
This year there's no such label. Just the standard Badatz which of course says "lo kollel Pesach" since it's kitniyot and the OU. I don't know if they do a special run for Pesach or if it's always kosher for Pesach and they just print a label differently for Pesach. Anyone who knows or can give me contact info to ask, would appreciate your help.

Welcome to MiYodeya Eric and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The OU does certify certain products as OU-Kitniyot. However, on their product search page, it appears that the Shibolim rice products are only certified OU-Pareve.
Seasons Kosher has a listing for the Kosher for Passover version, and it has an additional certification from Badatz Beit Yosef for Pesach. They are the ones you would have to contact in order to know if the product is Kosher for Pesach all year round. This site has some contact information; I don't know if it's accurate or current.
In cases where, for example, a product is certified OU-P year round, the company might choose to omit the -P during the year (sometimes because they're worried people will think it's old stock from last Pesach). However, since this is an additional hechsher that is only present on some bags, it's extremely unlikely that the additional hechsher is supervising the product for Pesach year-round, but the company only puts any logo for that hechsher during Passover time. My understanding would be that only products with the Pesach certification from Badatz Beit Yosef are actually certified for Pesach.

In many instances the product ingredients is always kosher for Passover. However, many certifications, OU amongst them, require a mashgiach temidi for a pesach run to ensure added supervision that nobody mistakenly ate in the area, or cross contaminated with another product. But the ingredients in many instances are the same.

@Chatzkel same ingredients doesn't mean same processes. Chometz equipment, for example, is not an issue year-round, but would need to be kashered for Pesach.
